# find_next_position() function in mtdoops.c

Tags: c, linux, kernel, panic

I am trying to understand the functionality of mtdoops.c file.

MTD device Partition is looked as a circular buffer for storing kernel oops messages.

Before writing any new kernel oops messages we are checking for the free pages in the mtd partition using below function.

Below is the function code of find_next_position function.

```
static void find_next_position(struct mtdoops_context *cxt)
{
    struct mtd_info *mtd = cxt->mtd;
    int ret, page, maxpos = 0;
    u32 count[2], maxcount = 0xffffffff;
    size_t retlen;

    for (page = 0; page < cxt->oops_pages; page++) {
            if (mtd_block_isbad(mtd, page * record_size))
                    continue;
            /* Assume the page is used */
            mark_page_used(cxt, page);
            ret = mtd_read(mtd, page * record_size, MTDOOPS_HEADER_SIZE,
                           &retlen, (u_char *)&count[0]);
            if (retlen != MTDOOPS_HEADER_SIZE ||
                            (ret < 0 && !mtd_is_bitflip(ret))) {
                    printk(KERN_ERR "mtdoops: read failure at %ld (%td of %d read), err %d\n",
                           page * record_size, retlen,
                           MTDOOPS_HEADER_SIZE, ret);
                    continue;
            }

            if (count[0] == 0xffffffff && count[1] == 0xffffffff)
                    mark_page_unused(cxt, page);
            if (count[0] == 0xffffffff || count[1] != MTDOOPS_KERNMSG_MAGIC)
                    continue;
            if (maxcount == 0xffffffff) {
                    maxcount = count[0];
                    maxpos = page;
            } else if (count[0] < 0x40000000 && maxcount > 0xc0000000) {
                    maxcount = count[0];
                    maxpos = page;
            } else if (count[0] > maxcount && count[0] < 0xc0000000) {
                    maxcount = count[0];
                    maxpos = page;
            } else if (count[0] > maxcount && count[0] > 0xc0000000
                                    && maxcount > 0x80000000) {
                    maxcount = count[0];
                    maxpos = page;
            }
    }
    if (maxcount == 0xffffffff) {
            cxt->nextpage = cxt->oops_pages - 1;
            cxt->nextcount = 0;
    }
    else {
            cxt->nextpage = maxpos;
            cxt->nextcount = maxcount;
    }

    mtdoops_inc_counter(cxt);
```

}

Here we are looping over all the pages available in the mtd partition.

> cxt->oops_pages = (mtd device partition size) / record size
>   where record size is 4096.

From the code we can understand that , MTD header information and magic pointer information is being stored in first 16bits of each page.

> Please help to understand the functionality of this function.
>
> > 1) Could not understand the hardcodings like 0xffffffff, 0x40000000 , 0xc0000000.
> >
> > 2) All the if/else condition is assigning same values . 
> >           why only those values are being checked ?
> >
> > 3) could not get sufficient information about MTD_HEADER format.

Complete source code of mtdoops.c can be found below.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/mtdoops.c

If any documentation link related to mtdoops can be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The function searches for the last record made by counter count[0] which is interpreted as kind of sequence number. As this counter can wrap-around as it reaches 0xffffffff maxcount should follow count[0] progressively neither than to be max of all sequence numbers. That's why if counter count[0] = 2, is met after maxcount has already reach, say (0xffffffff - 2), maxcount should become 2 (second "else-if")

```
} else if (count[0] < 0x40000000 && maxcount > 0xc0000000) {
```

All these ifdef-s to handle wrap-around of the counter.
I agree that this code is not very well written. Two last "if else-s", IMHO, can be done in one

```
} else if (count[0] > maxcount) {
```

I cannot imagine when condition

```
else if (count[0] > maxcount && count[0] > 0xc0000000
    && maxcount < 0x80000000) {
```

can be met.

Values 0xffffffff, 0x40000000 , 0xc0000000 are just convenient values to use. With the same success 0xc0000020 can be used instead of 0xc0000000.

I can see another strange things in this function like

```
if (mtd_block_isbad(mtd, page * record_size))
    continue
```

still iterates through the pages instead of skipping the whole bad block.